# Wait for Flutter widget to be built before visiting child elements

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I have a `TextField` which I've identified with a `GlobalKey`. In my `build` function, I am trying to get the `RenderEditable` from this `TextField` using `GlobalKey.currentContext.visitChildElements`.

Naturally, this requires the `TextField` to be built, but that wouldn't have happened when I called `visitChildElements` since I do that in the `build` function. I've tried to fix this by wrapping my search code in `SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` or `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` to search *after* the widget has been built. However, I still get `null` from `GlobalKey.currentContext` meaning the widget has not been built yet.

Why is this happening and how can I properly `visitChildElements` to extract the `RenderEditable` from my `TextField`?

Thanks

Comment: probably you can call `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` again in the callback until you get non null render object, but the question is why would you want that render object for? to me it smells like "XY Problem"

Comment: I suppose I could do repeated calls, but that seems like something else is incorrect. I need access to the `TextField`'s `RenderEditable` because I'm trying to make an animated cursor for it. `RenderEditable` has a bunch of nice functions for getting the cursor's position and stuff like that.

Comment: Specifically, I would like to have access to the RenderEditable when I add a listener to the `TextField`'s `TextEditingController` (which is assigned during `build`)

Comment: hmm ok I'm not sure if this will work in my context, but thanks for the suggestion. Do you know anything about `EditableTextState` and how that could be used with a stateless widget and a `TextField`? I realize I may need to be using a `EditableText` instead of `TextField` but I like how `TextField` already implements most of what I need.

Comment: `_TextFieldState` has `editableTextKey` property

Comment: How do you get access to `_TextFieldState`? It's not mentioned in the `TextField` documentation...

Comment: but actually using those GlobalKeys is a bad workaround, it's better to visit the Element tree to find those states and / or render objects

Comment: I’ve been using it to get cursor locations within a text fields. That stuff works. I’ve also been getting the `RenderEditable` by traversing the elements tree but I only know how to get the elements tree via a `GlobalKey`. Is there another way to get it?

Comment: with that you can get either `Stste` or `RenderObject` (see `_visitor` method for more details and the sample usage code): https://gist.github.com/pskink/115c546eaa8eb91d46b9877d0fc9c32f - note that  in the sample code there is no need for `VakueKey` when only one `TextField` is used